Как в цикле суммировать найденные значения верхнему уровню?
У меня есть категории, которые имеют/не имеют дочерние категории.
Также есть товары, которые принадлежат одной или нескольким категориям.
Мне нужно посчитать количество товаров у всех родительских категориях, включаю дочерние.
Я получаю такой php-массив, где ключ массива это ID категории, а в значении массива указано ID родителя, ID в базе и количество товаров конечной категории:
array (size=1505)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 30
      'parent_id' => null
      'count' => int 0
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 31
      'parent_id' => null
      'count' => int 0
  21 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 32
      'parent_id' => int 2
      'count' => int 0
  211 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 33
      'parent_id' => int 21
      'count' => int 5689
  212 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 34
      'parent_id' => int 21
      'count' => int 1547
  //...

Вот таким методом я получаю дочерние элементы только первого уровня. А мне нужно получить все дочерние категории.
foreach($tree as $id => $item) {
   if ($item['parent_id'] !== null) {
      $parent_id = $item['parent_id'];
      $tree[$parent_id]['childs'][] = $id;
   }
}

Каким образом я могу в родительской категории просуммировать количество товаров всех дочерних категорий?
Понятно, что нужно использовать цикл, но каким образом я не пойму :с

рекурсия вам в помощь. находите узлы, текущего уровня (сначала parent = null) и цикл по ним с заходом, каждый раз на фильтруете те где parent_id равен вашему текущему и опускаетесь вниз до самых листьев дерева. На обработном пути возвращаете сумму. В цикле эти частные суммы складываете и вписываете в узел.

@teran, можешь помочь показать на моем примере?

Не совсем понятна логика данного массива. parent_id это значение ключа с элементом или же надо искать по id элемента.
Логичнее было бы чтобы id 'элемента был бы ключом в данном массиве.
И тогда если есть уверенность, что в массиве сначала идут элементы верхнего уровня, а потом уже дочерние, то можно попробовать пройти массив с конца к началу и просто посчитать сумму как
$arr[$item['parent_id']]['count']+= $item['count'];

Т.е. для каждого элемента $item находим в основном массиве $arr его родительский элемент и прибавляем к сумме число из текущего элемента.
Если уверености в сортировке нет, то можно один раз пройти весь массив и сформировать для каждого элемента список id его дочерних элементов.
Как-то так
foreach($arr as $id => $item) {
  $parent_id = $item['parent_id'];
  if (!isset($arr[$parent_id]['childs']) {
     $arr[$parent_id]['childs'] = [];
  }
  $art[$patent_id]'childs'][] = $id;
}

А дальше уже с помощью массива childs можно пройти по всем элементам и посчитать суммы.

ты потрясающий!

Хотя нет, еще не потрясающий)) Во-первых, $arr[$parent_id] = []; скорее всего не нужно добавлять, т.к. он очищает элемент массива. А это делать нельзя, так как у этой категории тоже могут быть товары. А во-вторых, таким методом я собираю только дочерние элементы первого уровня. А мне нужно все дочерние. Я дополнил свой вопрос, чтобы было более читабельнее.

@Rediska поправил. Ошибка в коде. Это инициализация массива для дочерних элементов

но так ведь тоже не верно. Записываются категории только первого дочернего уровня. А мне нужны все до конечной))

@Rediskaа, а дальше уже обход по дочерним элементам в виде рекурсивной функции. Которая считает суммы для всех дочерних элементов. Но сначала проверяет что если у текущего дочернего элемента так же есть дети, то вызывает саму себя для этого элемента.
